# My addeventListener not working on click with a button

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Hello i have a login page and i want to when you click the button "login" it prints a message in the console but here it doesn't detect the button "login" i put query selector and took the class
html:

```js
 const inputs=document.querySelectorAll(".input");
let submit=document.querySelector(".btn");

submit.addEventListener('click' ,()=>{
console.log("test")
})
```

```html
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/XWdPc2X/wave-01.png" class="wave">
<div class="container">
    <div class="img">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/JvXP8rW/phone.png">
    </div>
    <div class="login-content">
        <form action="index.html" class="form-login">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/H4f3Hkv/profile.png">
            <h2 class="title">Welcome</h2>
            <div class="input-div one">
                <div class="i">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="div">
                    <h5>Username</h5>
                    <input type="text" class="input">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-div pass">
                <div class="i">
                    <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="div">
                    <h5>Password</h5>
                    <input type="password" class="input">
                </div>
            </div>
            <button id="send" class="btn btn-success mt-5">Login <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right ml-2 mt-1"></i></button>
            <!--  <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>-->
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the default `type` for a `button` is `submit`, so when you click the button, it attempts to redirect. Change the button's `type` to `button` to get your callback behavior.

```js
document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener('click' ,()=>{
  console.log("test")
})
```

```html
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/XWdPc2X/wave-01.png" class="wave">
<div class="container">
    <div class="img">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/JvXP8rW/phone.png">
    </div>
    <div class="login-content">
        <form action="index.html" class="form-login">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/H4f3Hkv/profile.png">
            <h2 class="title">Welcome</h2>
            <div class="input-div one">
                <div class="i">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="div">
                    <h5>Username</h5>
                    <input type="text" class="input">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-div pass">
                <div class="i">
                    <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="div">
                    <h5>Password</h5>
                    <input type="password" class="input">
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" id="send" class="btn btn-success mt-5">Login <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right ml-2 mt-1"></i></button>
            <!--  <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>-->
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Use `document.getElementById` selector to get element and add function `onClick`

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('send');

    btn.onclick = () => {
      console.log('here');
      // do something
    }
```

```html
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/XWdPc2X/wave-01.png" class="wave">
<div class="container">
    <div class="img">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/JvXP8rW/phone.png">
    </div>
    <div class="login-content">
        <form action="index.html" class="form-login">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/H4f3Hkv/profile.png">
            <h2 class="title">Welcome</h2>
            <div class="input-div one">
                <div class="i">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="div">
                    <h5>Username</h5>
                    <input type="text" class="input">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-div pass">
                <div class="i">
                    <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="div">
                    <h5>Password</h5>
                    <input type="password" class="input">
                </div>
            </div>
            <button id="send" class="btn btn-success mt-5">Login <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right ml-2 mt-1"></i></button>
            <!--  <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>-->
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This may work, but good answers on Stack Overflow should explain what the problem was in the first place and how your solution solves it. Also, the question was not tagged with JQuery, so the answer should not employ libraries, frameworks, or other technologies that weren't asked for. JQuery is overkill for this. See my answer.

Comment: thanks!, I did not see all question, then I changed my answer

Comment: The answer is still incorrect. See my answer.